# Nested HTML Table Tags Stripped Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a nested table, which will work by adding a row after the one clicked by the user and then within the new row, adding a table with additional details of the item shown.  An example of the type of nesting is shown below:

```html
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1a">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery picks up the user click and asks PHP for the detail, which it then appends as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/getDetail.php",
    data: {
        id: data_id
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#' + row_id).after(data);
    }
});
```

This adds the row to the original table, but it omits the enclosing tags for the nested table and you end up with this:

```html
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1a">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It appears that somewhere along the line, between the Jquery call and the browser rendering, the nested table tags are stripped out.  Has anyone else come across this before?

Comment: The problem is because your HTML is invalid. The nested `<table>` needs to be within a `<td>`, not a `<tr>`. The browser's HTML renderer is moving 
 the table location in your code to make it valid. Closing as a typo

Comment: You also have multiple elements with `id="1"`, which is invalid too. `id` attributes *must* be unique within the page

Comment: Thanks for the solution @RoryMcCrossan.  The two tables were meant to be before and after click, so there is only one ID of "1".

Comment: Ahh, ok. In that case it's just the nesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

The nested `table` can't be a direct child of `tr` you could add it inside a `tr` tag :

```
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1a">
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE :** The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, try to use common classes instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Rory McCrossan.  The below is the modified HTML for correct function:

```html
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1a">
    <td colspan=2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```